# full screen button in video tag missing

Tags: php, css, html

**full screen button in video tag missing when page containing video is loaded externally on another pages  div**

I have a page `external.php` . In this page when i use the following code

```
echo 
   '<video width="400" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>';
```

i get a video with full screen button in it on chrome.But when i try to load this `external.php` on another page `(home.php)` div the video is coming but the full screen button is missing.But in IE there is no such problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either solve this via *CSS* OR *Fullscreen API*.

**1. CSS**

I think you can accomplish this by changing the *css* for the #document fragments, these are DOM1 specs and supported by all browsers, but about the styling, I'm not sure. The following solution is *webkit* specific.

You need just to write this code in your css:

```
video::-webkit-media-controls-fullscreen-button {}
```

**2. Full screen API**

If you want to accomplish it by [Fullscreen API](http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/fullscreen/raw-file/tip/Overview.html) check below demo first:

[Demo Full screen video](http://www.thecssninja.com/demo/fullscreen/)

As you can see a very simple demo showing HTML5 video in full screen, make sure you're using *Chrome dev, webkit* or *firefox* nightly.

For more detail you can check it [here](http://www.thecssninja.com/javascript/fullscreen).
Browsers may provide a user interface, but shouldn't provide a programmable one.